# Vue How to fix 404 error when using nuxt proxy and nuxt axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

In my `vue`-app I'm using the `@nuxtjs/proxy` together with `@nuxtjs/axios` but for some reason I don't know, I always get an `Request failed with status code 404` -error when calling the api.

Here is my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
modules: [
 '@nuxtjs/axios',
 '@nuxtjs/proxy'
],

axios: {
  proxy: true,
},

proxy: {
  "/api": {
    target: "https://url-to-api.com/api",
    pathRewrite: { "^/api/": "" },
  } 
},
```

then in my `vue`-component

```js
created(){
  const { data } = await this.$axios.get(
    `/api/products/all`
  )
  ...
}
```

when I check on the network tab, the request is:

```
https://mypage.com/api/products/all
```

that request returns like mentioned above `Request failed with status code 404`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

nuxt version: 2.15.8

Try this:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

axios: {
  baseURL: '/',
  browserBaseURL: '/',
  proxy: true,
},

proxy: {
  '/api/': {
    target: process.env.BASE_URL,
    pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''},
  },
},

publicRuntimeConfig: {
  axios: {
    browserBaseURL: process.env.BROWSER_BASE_URL,
  },
},

privateRuntimeConfig: {
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  },
},
```

and in your component:

```js
created(){
  const { data } = await this.$axios.get(
    `products/all`
  );
}
```

in `.env`:

```
BROWSER_BASE_URL=/api/
BASE_URL=https://url-to-api.com/api/
```

it works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).